# Circuits newb needs someone to help with a diagram

Tags: layout, obd

I'm trying to build an OBDII circuit for a STN1110 chip from [OBD Solutions](http://www.obdsol.com/stn1110/). My problem is I don't understand some of the values needed. For instance, the [datasheet](http://www.scantool.net/scantool/downloads/97/stn1110-ds.pdf) has most of the information I need, but in the ISO transceiver I cannot understand what the Q's are or what their values need to be. Also how do I tell what the right LM339 chip is? There are like 6 different versions on mouser.

[image]

Also, if anyone can tell me the difference between DLC_RAW and just DLC I would appreciate it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Q are NPN bipolar junction transistors, they do not have an specific value, you have to find the right transistor for the application. Regarding the LM339 most likely you are looking at different packages in which they come in I recommend you go with a DIP(dual in line package)[Like this one](http://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/LM339N/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtYFXwiBRPs0%252bm1HQp6xrWl). The diffence between DLC_RAW and DLC is that a DLC_RAW is a signal comming from the outside and is unprotected, while the DLC is protected againg reversed polarity by the diode, current limited by the PTC fuse, and over voltage protected by the ESD protected by the TVS diode, and filtered out the high frequencies by the capacitors

Comment: Forgive me, but is this an okay choice? http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Fairchild-Semiconductor/2N5551BU/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMshyDBzk1%2fWi6kfu%252bQlsU6S4rLOEhMXA0o%3d

Comment: I think that for that ISO transceiver application your choice of NPN BJT might be suitable

Answer (score 1):

The Q1 and Q2 are some type of Transistor. They seam to invert the signal ISO_K/L_TX. (Keep an eye on the speed when selecting)

When looking for a special chip, you will normally find several versions. They differ in the used footprint, temperature range and sometimes also quality.

Comment: How do I tell what a proper transistor would be?